# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, build.gradle

I have created project with Androidx support and the below are the dependencies for my `build.gradle` file.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

But while try to integrate another android library(.aar) and getting the below error, can any one suggest the workaround for this?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity;
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~sZEp0KvV8gcfSkrgZ7B96A==/com.example.upiandroidsdk-hgQiGx156STD8ciVSeaJxA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~sZEp0KvV8gcfSkrgZ7B96A==/com.example.upiandroidsdk-hgQiGx156STD8ciVSeaJxA==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~sZEp0KvV8gcfSkrgZ7B96A==/com.example.upiandroidsdk-hgQiGx156STD8ciVSeaJxA==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
```

Comment: Check if you have the correct import, not sure why it's trying to find android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity it should be this
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity instead.

Comment: @sunil, I think that library (.aar) using v7 AppCompatActivity. That is the reason if we trigger that activity getting that error

Comment: Yeah then you have to exclude com.android.support from your aar.

Comment: @Sunil: since it is a third party library how we can exclude this? can you please suggest the approach.

Comment: implementation('your.aar.library') {
        exclude  group:'com.android.support', module:'appcompat-v7'
    }
did you already tried this?

Comment: @sunil: yes but no luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249439/discussion-between-vishnu-and-sunil-sunny).

Answer (score 0):

You could try exclude v7 through this way:

```
    implementation('you.library') {
        exclude  group:'com.android.support', module:'appcompat-v7'
    }
```

Or force to use your androidx library in app:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1' }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried second approach but not working and getting same error. Actually have created seperate folder under project and added .aar file because we are building .aar file with another .aar. I have added dependency in gradle.build like this:  `implementation project(":newlib") `